# Multiple Subversion clients and TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I installed Subversion 1.5.x and then TortoiseSVN 1.6.x.

All was fine using the 1.5.x command line utility exclusively.  After becoming comfortable with svn for awhile, I then used the TortoiseSVN client to make a commit, which worked, but the command line client now gives me a client too old, get a newer client error on all commands.

1 - Did I corrupt my working copy?  I don't think so, as TortoiseSVN works fine.

2 - I think I just have to download the 1.6.x command line client and use this if I want to use command line svn at the same time as TortoiseSVN.  According to the TSVN FAQ, clients can install "on top" of one another, whatever that means.

If this is so, how do I bypass the old command line client?

I assume I just run the newer svn.exe either by running it directly or altering the environment path or the install package will put the newer svn directory at the end of the path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recently had the same problem in a project; a user had TortoiseSVN 1.6 and automated builds used 1.5, which gave the client too old message. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802348/subversion-getting-the-client-is-too-old-even-though-all-devs-are-running-the-sa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of the working copy changed with subversion 1.6. When you used TortoiseSVN 1.6, your working copy was automatically updated to that new format, and can now no longer be read by older subversion clients (such as your 1.5 binaries).

Simply replace your subversion 1.5 client binaries with the current version 1.6.2 and everything should work again.

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers.  

I installed 1.6.x from CollabNet and svn from the command line works now.  

The installer removed the old svn client pathname from the path and tacked on the new client path to the path environment variable.  I thought that might affect the Subversion server, but everything seems to work ok.

Answer (score 1):

SVN 1.5 and 1.6 use different format for the working copy information. When you used a 1.6 client, it automatically converts your working copy, making previous clients unable to use your working copy. And there is no way back.

You are correct that the good solution is to download the svn 1.6 command line client. Or to downgrade your TortoiseSVN to 1.5 a re-do a checkout.