# [SVN]: Using two Subversion clients

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

I have a working folder. I use Commit by right-clicking on it after my work is over and TortoiseSVN commits to a repository in my local computer. I am using Aptana for my development and recently added Subversive plugin. I want to link the same working folder with Subversive. For this I created a new repository in a different folder. Later, I used the Aptana Import option to import my existing working folder into this new repository.

I want to know whether it will work fine or not. I suspect, the revision numbers may get overwritten.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little lost with this question. In subversion, everyone works on the same repository, there should be no need to create a new one, is that really what you meant? Also, you wouldn't need to re-import a working copy - you should just be able to open the existing one, or at worst, do a new checkout. These terms have specific meaning in svn, so I'm wondering if you mean something else.

Comment: If you're having trouble, I can really recommend these two places: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/, http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you created *two* different repositories for the same code. This is almost certainly not what you want to do.

A "working copy" in Subversion is attached to exactly one repository. It's not possible (and you wouldn't want to) use the same working copy with more than one repository. This just isn't something that makes sense.

As long as your tools (TortoiseSVN, Subversive) use compatible Subversion working copy formats (same x.y version number), then you should be able to use them with the same working copy and the same repository.

Answer (score 1):

It either should work or you should get an error. You won't get data corruption.

See these questions:

- [Multiple Subversion clients and TortoiseSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944589/multiple-subversion-clients-and-tortoisesvn)
- [svn client/server versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508466/svn-client-server-versions)

Comment: It's working but using Subversive later, overwrote Tortoise version numbers.

Comment: What do you mean "overwrote"? If you update the project, the revision does change. That's what update does, no matter from which client you do it ... :/

Comment: @Aaron: Previously TortoiseSVN Browser was showing a file with version 28, but now it is showing 1.

Comment: That really shouldn't happen unless you told one of the clients to checkout version 1. But maybe you've found a bug in TSVNCache. Check whether you have the latest version.